# Validar información para exportación

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, script

Amigos buenos días, he estado haciendo varias exportaciones en estos días, la mayoría ha estado relativamente accesible debido a que son transacciones que estoy exportando por fechas, adjunto ejemplo de una de mis exportaciones:

```
INSERT [192.168.100.24\SQLEXPRESS].[INT_IQWARE].[dbo].[T_DIARIO_TRANS]
SELECT
IdDiarioTrans,
'01/01/2000',
Fecha,
Folio,
Subfolio,
Habitacion,
Referencia,
IDTipoTransaccion,
TipoTransaccion,
ShortName,
Debito,
Credito,
Comentario,
'',
0,
0,
'',
''
FROM [T_DIARIO_TRANS]
WHERE (Fecha = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate - 1 FROM prProperty))
```

El problema que se me presenta ahora es que necesito hacer una exportacion de una tabla que no incluye fecha, cómo puedo hacer para validar los datos que estoy exportando? Esto con el fin de no exportar transacciones que ya se hayan exportado previamente? Acá ejemplo de esta segunda exportación:

```
INSERT INTO [INT_IQWARE].[dbo].[T_FACTURACLI_FILAS]
SELECT
IDFactura,
Linea,
Descripcion,
IDTipoTransaccion,
TipoTransaccion,
ShortName,
Total
FROM [T_FACTURACLI_FILAS]
```

Comment: Esta pregunta no se puede contestar, sin saber muchas cosas, y cuando nos las digas la vas a poder contestar vos solo. por ejemplo. El id de factura es secuencial incremental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ese caso imagino que el encabezado de la factura si tiene la fecha, por tanto puedes hacer un join que te permita filtrar los datos insertados.

```
INSERT INTO [INT_IQWARE].[dbo].[T_FACTURACLI_FILAS]
SELECT
IDFactura,
Linea,
Descripcion,
IDTipoTransaccion,
TipoTransaccion,
ShortName,
Total
FROM [T_FACTURACLI_FILAS]ff
inner join TABLA_FACTURAS f
  on f.IDFactura = ff.IdFactura
where F.fechaFactura <= 'YYYYMMDD'
```